# Expectation of a family of random variables

Tags: evaluation, random

I did some search here, but seems that no one asked about this.

I want to define a family of independent and identically distributed random variables, $x_1,...,x_n$, and then calculates the expected value of some expressions like $\sum_{i,j=1}^nx_ix_j$. The result would be some function depending on $n$. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a general solution for any distribution whose moments exist ...

**Notation**
Define the power sum $s_r$:

$$s_r=\sum _{i=1}^n X_i^r$$

**The Problem**

Let $\left(X_1,\ldots,X_n\right)$ denote $n$ iid random variables. This is the same problem as drawing a random sample of size $n$ from a population random variable $X$. The problem is to find:

$$E\Big(\sum_{i,j=1}^n X_i X_j\Big)  = E\Big [\Big (\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\Big)^2\Big ]  = E\Big [s_1^2\Big]$$

This is a problem known as finding *moments of moments*: they can be very difficult to solve by hand, but quite easy to solve with the help of a computer algebra system, for any arbitrary symmetric power sum. In this instance, we seek the expectation of $s_1^2$ ... *i.e.* the 1st raw moment of $s_1^2$ ... so the solution (expressed `ToRaw` moments of the population) is:

[image]

where `RawMomentToRaw` is a function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*, and where $\acute{\mu }_1$ and $\acute{\mu }_2$ denote the 1st and 2nd raw moments of random variable $X$, whatever its distribution (assuming they exist). All done.

**More detail**

There is an extensive discussion of *moments of moments* in Chapter 7 of our book:

- Rose and Smith,  "*Mathematical Statistics with Mathematica*", Springer, NY

A free download of the chapter is available here:

http://www.mathstatica.com/book/Rose_and_Smith_2002edition_Chapter7.pdf

---

## Examples

**Example 1:** The Normal Distribution

If $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then:
$$\acute{\mu }_1  = E[X] = \mu  \quad  \text{ and } \quad \acute{\mu }_2  = E[X^2]  = \mu^2 + \sigma^2 $$

Substituting in $\acute{\mu }_1$ and $\acute{\mu }_2$ in `Out[1]` yields the solution:  $$E\Big(\sum_{i,j=1}^n X_i X_j\Big) = n \left(n \mu ^2 + \sigma ^2\right)$$

**Simple check:** The Normal case with $n = 3$

In the case of $n = 3$, the joint pdf of $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ is say $f(x_1, x_2, x_3)$:

[image]

The sum of products we are interested in is:

[image]

and the desired expectation is:

[image]

which matches perfectly the general $n$-Normal solution derived above, but with $n = 3$.

---

**Example 2:** The Uniform Distribution

If $X \sim Uniform(a,b)$ (as considered in both other answers), then:
$$\acute{\mu }_1  = E[X] = \frac{a+b}{2}  \quad  \text{ and } \quad  \acute{\mu }_2  = E[X^2]  = \frac{1}{3} \left(a^2+a b+b^2\right)$$

Substituting in $\acute{\mu }_1$ and $\acute{\mu }_2$  in `Out[1]` yields the solution:  $$E\Big(\sum_{i,j=1}^n X_i X_j\Big) =\frac{1}{3} n \left(a^2+a b+b^2\right)+\frac{1}{4} (n-1) n (a+b)^2$$

Again, this is different to the other answers posted - and much more complicated. Again, it is easy to perform a quick check:

**Simple check:** The Uniform case with $n = 3$

In the case of $n = 3$, the joint pdf of $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ is say $g(x_1, x_2, x_3)$:

[image]

and the desired expectation is:

[image]

which matches perfectly our general $n$-Uniform solution derived above, with $n = 3$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: Thanks wolfies. I have to admit, I wasn't aware about what was the correct expectation and I just start to use Mathematica. That's why I couldn't know if the accepted answer was indeed correct. I just changed this, thank you very much for helping.

Comment: But still, you made manipulations with $n$ random variables to explain, but made the codes using only 3 random variables. I still don't know how to define $n$ random variables and calculates the expectation of some expression with them. Could you show the code to calculate $E (\sum_{i,j=1}^nX_iX_j)$ in the first example (and get as answer $n(n\mu^2+\sigma^2)$) ?
Thanks.

Comment: I was looking for some symbolic calculations, in which $n$ is not assigned to a value. I want that Mathematica calculates some expectations in the same way you get the result $n(n\mu^2 + \sigma^2)$, doing only symbolic calculations. It is possible to get a lot of relevant results this way, and that is what I'm looking for.

Comment: I did some tests here, looks like the code 

`d = NormalDistribution[0, \[Sigma]];  
Expectation[x^n, x \[Distributed] d]`

give me a symbolic answer, which is exactly what I want to work with. If Mathematica does that, it should be able to compute expectations of polynomial of random variables iid, and shouldn't be necessary to say how many random variables, the program should be able to deal with a sum and some expression inside the sum, Its just a matter of deal with indexes.

Comment: @Integral wrote:  "Could you show the code to calculate $E\Big(\sum_{i,j=1}^n X_i X_j\Big)$ ..." ////////////////  The code is shown. It is simply:  `RawMomentToRaw`[1, $s_1^2$] , using the `RawMomentToRaw` function from the _mathStatica_ package for _Mathematica_. That is all.

Comment: ok, and how do I define s1? Not with 3 or 4 random varibles, but with n, and them do symbolic work.

Comment: You don't have to define $s_1$. You just type $s_1$, and the function knows what it is. The solution above is self-contained and complete. Out[1] is it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example, expected sum of *n* uniform random variates with specified minimums and maximums:

```
dt = TransformedDistribution[Sum[v1*v2, {x, 1, n}], 
       {v1 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{min1, max1}], 
        v2 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{min2, max2}]}];

exp=Expectation[x, x \[Distributed] dt]

(* 1/4 (max1+min1) (max2+min2) n *)
```

Check it with a simulation:

```
{min1, max1, min2, max2} = {1, 10, 20, 50};
v1sim = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{min1, max1}], {100000}];
v2sim = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{min2, max2}], {100000}];
v1sim*v2sim // Total // AccountingForm
exp /. {min1 -> 1, max1 -> 10, min2 -> 20, max2 -> 50, n -> 100000}

(*

19198729.

19250000

*)
```

Comment: Maybe I got this wrong, but looks to me that your n random variables are not i.i.d., they all depend on $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Comment: The names don't matter -- they are just symbols, and don't have any effect on the answer. It works just as well when written: `dt = TransformedDistribution[Sum[x1*x2, {i, 1, n}], {x1 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{min1, max1}], x2 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{min2, max2}]}];`

Comment: Im having trouble to define define $\sum_{i,j=1}^nx_ix_j$, in the case that the $x_i$ are $N(0,1)$. The expected value should be $n$ but Im always getting $0$. How do I exactly do that sum?

Comment: @Integral: If the *N* in your comment is the normal distribution, then that (0) *is* the expectation.

Comment: Im not sure about that, this sum will have squared terms, and $E(x_i^2) = 1$, because the variance of the $x_i$`s are 1.

Comment: For example, for $n=2$ we can write 

d = TransformedDistribution[(Sum[x[i], {i, 1, 2}])^2, {x[
     1] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1], 
   x[2] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]}];

 Expectation[x, x \[Distributed] d]

and the expectation will be $2$, I want to do that for $n$ variables and get some formula, which will depend on $n$.